# How to edit/ write rinex observation and navigation file using python?

Tags: python, gps

I have read both rinex observation and navigation files using python and saved all the ephemeris data in dataframe and changed the values as I needed. Now i need to create new rinex observation and navigation files with the updated variable values.

I tried to figure out any available packages but couldn't find any.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @СергейКох I saved the clock, ephemeris, and integrity variables (SVclockBias, SVclockDrift, SVclockDriftRate, IODE, Crs ,DeltaN.... etc.) in a panda dataframe from a navigation file downloaded from NASA cddis. I changed the data based on my requirement and now I want to create a new navigation file using the updated data. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked at this package? https://pypi.org/project/georinex/